# existence of smooth points on varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, jacobian

$P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ are algebraically independent irreducible homogeneous polynomials in $n$ variables over the field of complex numbers. Then, is it true that there is a point $b = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)$ such that $\forall i \in [k], P_i(b) = 0$ and the rank of the Jacobian of $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ at $b$ is equal to $k$ ?

If this is false, a counterexample would also be very helpful.

Comment: Note that your question is not about varieties, where the answer would be affirmative; Every complex variety has a smooth point. However, if stated as is, you can consider a scheme which is nowhere reduced to construct a counterexample. A simple example would be $P_1=yz-x^2$ and $P_2=y$ in $\Bbb C[x,y,z]$, whose zeros are of the form $(0,t,0)$ and the Jacobian of $P$ is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 
-2x & z & y \\
 0  & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
whose rank at any such point is one.

Comment: Thank you Jesko! However, I am not from this area, and need a quick clarification - when you say a variety, do you mean an irreducible variety ? So, if in addition to the conditions in the question, it was also known the variety defined by $P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_k$ is irreducible, then the statement is true ?

Comment: My comment was more about reducedness, i.e. you need to have $I=\sqrt{I}$, where $I$ is the ideal generated by the $P_i$. Contrarily, I am sure you do not have to require the variety to be irreducible.

Comment: By the way, for some reason I wrote that the zeros of my first example are of the form $(0,t,0)$, which is of course wrong, they have the form $(0,0,t)$ when using coordinates $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you furthermore suppose that the variety defined by $I=(P_1, \ldots, P_k)$ is irreducible, then the answer is yes (apart from a silly counterexample in dimension 1 which can be straightforwardly corrected). Denote by $Z(J)$ the zero locus of the ideal $J$, and $I(V)$ the ideal of polynomials which are zero over $V$. Recall that by Nustellensatz $I(Z(J) ) = \sqrt{J}$.

Infact, let $D_{(i_1\ldots i_k)}$ be the determinant of the $(i_1, \ldots, i_k)$ minor of the jacobian matrix. Take an irreducible factor $f_{(i_1 \ldots i_k)}$ of $D_{(i_1\ldots i_k)}$; the ideal generated by $f$'s are prime ideals of height 1.

Suppose by absurd that the thesis is false. Then 
$$\sqrt{I} \subseteq \bigcup_{i_1, \ldots i_k} \sqrt{(D_{(i_1, \ldots i_k)})} \subseteq \bigcup_{i_1, \ldots i_k} (f_{(i_1, \ldots i_k)}) $$
because every time $b \in Z(I)$, then $Jac_{P_i}(b)$ is not of full rank, so there is a minor which has zero determinant, so $b \in Z(D_{(i_1, \ldots i_k)})$ for some $i$'s (you get an extra $\sqrt{ }$ because of nustellensatz).

Now if a prime is contained in a union of primes, it is containd in one of them, so $\sqrt{I} \subset (f_{(i_1 \ldots i_k)})$. If $k > 1$, you have a prime $\sqrt{I}$ (here we use the irreducibility hypothesis) of height $k$ contained in a prime of height $1$, which is an absurd. This follows from the fact that the transcendence degree of $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/\sqrt{I}$ is $n-k$ by the assumption on algebraic independence, so it has krull dimension $n-k$; this implies that the height of $\sqrt{I}$ is $k$, because of the formula $ht(p)+dim(A/p)$ in a domain $A$.

If $k=1$, then you should assume that $P$ is itself irreducible; this is not implied by the hypothesis of irreducibility on algebraic set because you can take powers of an irreducible and still get an irreducible variety. Otherwise $f(x)=x^2$ is a counterexample to the thesis. However, if $P$ is irreducible then $P$ and $D_i =\partial_{x_i}P$ are relatively prime, so it can'th happen that $(P) \subset (f_i)$.

**Remark.** The conditions $D_{(i_1 \ldots i_k)}(b) \neq 0$ are open conditions. We have seen that the open set $U \subset Z(I)$ in which this hold is non-empty. But $Z(I)$ is irreducible, so $U$ is dense: this means that indeed the jacobian is almost always of maximal rank in $Z(I)$!

Comment: Thanks very much! This was really helpful.

Comment: the proof is unfortunately flawed: the statement that $\sqrt I \subseteq \bigcup_{i_1,\ldots,i_k} \sqrt{(D_{(i_1,\ldots,i_k)})}$ does not hold in general, see my above example in the comments.

Comment: Ah, I see.I guess, I haven't followed everything. Will think more and write back.